# What exactly did the Outer Planets Panel say in their recommendation for outer planets missions?

Tags: nasa, history, deep-space, outer-planets

In the 1960s, James Van Allen's *Outer Planets Panel* made a proposal that NASA begin planning missions to the outer planets, that eventually led to Pioneer 10 and 11.  I've found many sources that mention it briefly.  [This one](https://books.google.com/books?id=9WfMExUYtvIC&pg=PA16&lpg=PA16) is characteristic:

> During this same period an Outer Planets Panel associated with NASA's Lunar and Planetary Missions Board (also chaired by Van Allen) recommended in 1962 that planning should start for low-cost exploratory missions to the outer planets.

Does the text of this recommendation survive?  What exactly did they say?

Comment: I think you got the year wrong, the Outer Planets Panel of the Lunar and Planetary Missions Board (LPMB) was formed in 1967 (see _Development of the U.S. Program for Investigation of the Outer Solar System_, page 353 of [A Strategy For Investigation Of The Outer Solar System](http://eaps4.mit.edu/research/papers/SSR14_1973b.pdf)). Recommendations influenced Announcement of Opportunity (AO) for "Asteroid/Jupiter Missions" (June 10, 1968), but were published a year later in [The Outer Solar System: A Program for Exploration, Report of a Study](https://books.google.com/books?id=Z5krAAAAYAAJ).

Comment: Also see this American Institute of Physics' [Finding Aid to the James A. Van Allen Papers, 1938-1990](https://www.aip.org/history/ead/19990077_content.html).

Answer (score 2):

In general, NASA published selected documents as to their exploration policies since inception in Exploring the Unknown Vol. 5: Exploring the Cosmos (copy at http://history.nasa.gov/SP-4407/ETUv5.pdf). You should be able to find specifics as to your question there.

Comment: Try II-21–II-23, which concerns planetary exploration objectives circa 1967.